# how to enlarge an image (any type) from c# without losing quality

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, c#-4.0

question says it all..

app would be in asp.net and c# (4.0)

Comment: How can you enlarge an image without losing quality? Unless if it's vector based, of course.

Comment: @klausbyskov: This is soooo possible. I've seen it on CSI many times: "Enhance!" ;-) Gets really sharp too...

Comment: I think that's built in to the Macs they use on CSI... just say "Enhance" and you get an 1280x720 HD-res image from three pixels...

Comment: I wonder if this is indeed programming related :)

Comment: Hang on while I take a picture of Mars using my camera phone. Then we'll pass it into your app and enlarge it so we can find the Mars Rover :)

Answer (score 8):

This is impossible. Just think of the very simple case of a 10 x 10 bitmap with 8-bit color. Therefore there are 10 * 10 * 8 = 800 bits of information. Now try to enlarge this to a 100 x 100 bitmap with 8-bit color. This requires 80000 bits of information. Where is that extra information going to come from? There are all sorts of [interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation) schemes for trying guess what the information should be but that's the best we can do. There must be a loss of quality as we don't know what the information should be.

Here are some interpolation schemes:

1. [Nearest neighbor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest-neighbor_interpolation)
2. [Bilinear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation)
3. [Bicubic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation)
4. [hq2x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hq2x)

These methods have different qualities. Some lead to jaggedness (nearest neighbor), others lead to a softening of the image (bilinear) and others lead to [ringing artifacts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringing_artifacts) (bicubic).

Answer (score 6):

If you enlarge an image beyond its original size, you lose quality.  There is no way around that.

That said, there are different methods/algorithms for resizing, some of which may introduce less quality degradation than others.  Experiment with the resizing parameters to figure out which works best for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

It's not impossible! Check out the [Genuine Fractals](http://www.ononesoftware.com/detail.php?prodLine_id=7) plug-in.   It uses "fractal based interpolation algorithms" to enlarge an image without losing quality.

It's a plugin for Photoshop, but illustrates that high-quality enlargement is indeed possible. (I wonder whether it's possible to invoke it via a .Net application? Hmmm...)

Comment: That is still interpolation. That is, it's still just an intelligent guess.

Comment: True, it's still interpolation. However I've seen it used to produce large-scale graphics for trade shows, and the results are fantastic. Also consider the viewing distance. A billboard graphic might not look great from 10" away... but looks fine when viewed from a more appropriate distance.